# difference between these two return statements in php

Tags: php, conceptual

we are wondering what is the best way to return `empty` `null` `no result` in php, we often use this

```
function doThis($a){
   if($a == 0){
       return '';
   }else{
       // complex mysql 
       return $result;
}
```

one more way of doing it is

```
function doThis($a){
   if($a == 0){
       return null;
   }else{
       // complex mysql 
       return $result;
}
```

now we compare like this

```
if(doThis(5)){
    // do something
}
```

or

```
if(!is_null(doThis(5)){
    // do something
}
```

i was wondering what is the best approach for doing this ?

Comment: use `==` to compare not `=` here `$a = 0`

Comment: It is nice to have only one return type. If you return result of a query and the result is empty, return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your function `doThis` near `if($a = 0){`.

`==` is used to compare.

`=` is used to assign value.

Answer (score 0):

`Null` means "nothing". The var has not been initialized.

False means "not true in a boolean context". Used to explicitly show you are dealing with logical issues.

0 is an int. Nothing to do with the rest above, used for mathematics.

`if($a = 0)` this will assign the value not compare
you need to try  `if($a == 0)`

Comment: what about `return '';`

Answer (score 0):

Speaking about "the best way" without context makes no sense. Generally you should write code to achieve those:

## "empty" return value should make sense to code which is using it

There are common cases of which empty value is to choose for given non-empty value.

For example, if you're searching for the specific entity in database. In case of success your code returns object, so that obviously should not be empty string in case of failed lookup. Common practice is to return null or [NullObject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) in that case.

If your code returns multiple objects in case of success, then you might want to return empty array/iterator in case of failure.

If your code operates strings, you generally don't want to return null at some point.

The most obvious case: if you're returning `true` in case of success, you should not return empty string in case of failure.

So, *use common sense rules and a bit of logic to figure out right return value*.

## code should be readable and valid

Also depends on context: if there is a difference in your case if function returns `null`, `''` or `false`, you should use additional checks of return value (mind using good name for check method). If your code does not care whats inside unless its an object, then `if($something)` will be enough.

These rules are usually valid for any programming language, not for PHP only.